# Scrapy, Twisted Critical Error : ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, twisted

I was running my scrapy code just fine until I got an error about not finding my module when calling "scrapy crawl file". I did not recall changing anything important and this error came out of nowhere.

I reinstalled scrapy and now I have a new error:

```
2019-05-27 17:39:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2019-05-27 17:39:19 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\Me\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 172, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\Me\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 176, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\Me\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1613, in unwindGenerator
    return _cancellableInlineCallbacks(gen)
  File "c:\users\Me\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1529, in _cancellableInlineCallbacks
    _inlineCallbacks(None, g, status)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "c:\users\Me\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "c:\users\Me\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 82, in crawl
    yield self.engine.open_spider(self.spider, start_requests)
builtins.ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

2019-05-27 17:39:19 [twisted] CRITICAL:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\Me\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "c:\users\Me\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 82, in crawl
    yield self.engine.open_spider(self.spider, start_requests)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I tried to look into the file directories and crawler.py is still there. Some other posts told me to instal pywin32 but I had that already so I reinstalled to no avail. I even copied the base constructor to mine and it still doesnt work. Any help is appreciated.

My simplified code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import math
from datetime import date
from collections import deque

class mySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myScraper'

    #requests
    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.msn.com/en-ca/'
        ]
        self.link_queue = deque()
        self.headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36 OPR/60.0.3255.109'}
        for url in urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse, endpoint = 'render.html', args = {'wait': 7}, headers = self.headers)

    #response
    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

Comment: It works for me. Maybe reinstall scrapy_splash: `python -m pip install scrapy_splash`

Comment: @pguardiario I just did and still have same error. How would I go about completely uninstalling python and starting over again? I am using anaconda python 3 on a virtual environment. Would I just create a new one?

Comment: You mean a windows VM? That seems like a painful way to go about it.

Comment: @pguardiario I fixed it by remaking the virtual environment, installing, and running the code. Thanks!